# Is there a way to view OSX's colored file labels while browsing through the network from a windows computer

Tags: windows-7, macos, colors, afp, label

Is there a way to view OSX's colored file labels while browsing through the network from a windows computer?

My media center Mac based PC has a bunch of files on it, that i use colored labels to highlight certain files that i am ''extra interested in'.  When i connect to a file share using WINDOWS7's file explorer, i cannot see the colored labels.   Is there a utility, or plugin to reveal the color.

Comment: like your username @lowbloodsugar :P

Comment: I doubt it.  The colors are stored as metadata in the MAC file system but windows browsing uses SMB (windows file sharing) which is not likely able to access that metadata.

Comment: @Chris Nava not quite! This isn't a particular feature of HFS+ as far as I'm concerned. You can access those metadata files through SMB as well, it's just a matter of parsing and representation.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a plugin or utility that does this for Windows 7 file explorer.
There is a similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122168/has-any-program-used-ds-store-or-the-like-for-something-useful

To my knowledge I don't know of any useful way of using the .DS_STORE files or resource forks on a non Mac machine.